# robocopy or xcopy: copy directory and files

Tags: windows, xcopy, robocopy

I want to use either robocopy or xcopy to copy a directory and its contents to a remote share.

I have attempted this:

```
xcopy /E /V /C /I /H /Y "foo" \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp
foo\file.sql foo\file2.cmd
2 File(s) copied
```

This doesn't copy foo directory, though.

This will copy files and directories from the remote path to a local path:

```
robocopy \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp bar /E
```

But reversing it doesn't make a difference:

```
robocopy foo \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /E

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         2
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         3
   Bytes :     2.0 k     2.0 k         0         0         0     1.2 k
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

As you see, the directory foo was not copied over.

So what can be done to copy local directories+files to a remote path?

---edit---

with `robocopy foo \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /copyall /E`

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         2
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         3
   Bytes :     2.0 k     2.0 k         0         0         0     1.2 k
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :               67419 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :               3.857 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Tuesday, September 20, 2016 10:25:27 PM
```

---edit2---

```
robocopy "C:\directory here\foo" \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /copyall /e
```

Results in the same: contents of foo copied to temp on destination, but not the foo directory itself.

---edit3---

```
robocopy "C:\directory here" \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /copyall /E
```

This will copy all contents and directories (including foo) inside "directory here", but I can't do that for this. foo contains just two files, but I need the directory. I must be doing something wrong with robocopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a directory `\\172.16.254.41\c$\temp\foo` you have to ask for one:

```
robocopy /e foo \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp\foo
```

Comment: AH, this works! I didn't know I'd need to tell robocopy the name of the directory to create.

Comment: Good job, I didn't know that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/copyall` snippet to robocopy

```
robocopy full_path_to_your_foo_folder \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /copyall /e
```

I assume that \172.16.254.41\c$\temp is your destination folder.

Comment: What about the initial path for foo folder? From your edit, I see that you are trying to copy FOLDER to remote path, no folderPATH to remote path. Try full path of foo folder as source folder path.

Comment: robocopy "C:\directory here\foo" \\172.16.254.41\c$\temp /copyall /e